# Run Third Party Apps from Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

Apologies for the very basic question. I want to run two third party CLI's (Command Line Interfaces) from a Jenkins Freestyle project running on Ubuntu.

Should I install these into a specific folder for Jenkins or under the Jenkins user account to ensure they are found and executed?

Answer (score 1):

First you need to navigate to your Jenkins UI screen .

-> Inside Jenkins go to ‘Manage Jenkins’

-> then go to ‘Manage Plugins’

There you will find a tab called ‘Advanced’ , there you just have to type the third party tool name .

Here you go, if the plugin is there in available option.You can just install the plugin from there.

Then configure the third party tool inside the particular job.

Comment: Just to be clear, these are not plug-ins. They are command line executables not designed at all for Jenkins.

Answer (score 0):

You have got two options:

1. Install the 3rd party CLI's as root and use them from jenkins.
2. Install the 3rd party CLI's as user jenkins in a specific directory for jenkins.

I commonly prefer the second alternative. If you just want to use the CLI's from/as jenkins this is definitly the best way.